# How does this website create the buttons on the homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://wufoo.com/

How does the website create the cool buttons on the homepage? With CSS, JavaScript? The hover effect is the best i've seen.

The buttons i'm on about are 'Custom Branding' etc!

Comment: can right click and view the source there

Comment: looks like [css transforms](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=css3%20transform%20tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is created using CSS3 transitions and a hover effect.

When the link is hovered, the background position is changed, and a transition causes it to animate smoothly.

Additionally, each link contains an icon in the upper-right. The icons are then transformed to rotate and scale, again with transitions which cause them to animate smoothly.

Comment: In addition, the icon in the corner is a font: `font-family: "Pictos";`